# Typescript error: TS2345: Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now so I figured I'd ask some help.

This is my function:

```
export function fetchToken(username: String, password: String) {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchTokenStart());
    try {
      const response = await Axios.post("login", {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      });
      dispatch(fetchTokenSucceed(response.data));
    } catch (error) {
      const response: errorResponse = error as errorResponse;
      dispatch(fetchTokenFailure(response.response.data));
    }
  };
}
```

And here I try to utilize it:

```
onClick={() => {
  dispatch(fetchToken("username", "password"));
}}
```

But then, on the fetchToken I get this Typescript error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the full code for your example. We are missing several pieces like the `fetchTokenStart` return type.

From what I understand, you are using redux and here you are getting an error because `dispatch` function accepts objects, usually in the format :

```
{
  type: string
  payload: any
}
```

Here you are passing an asynchronous function (returning Promise) as parameter for the `dispatch` function which is invalid. You can find more [information here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#dispatching-actions) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to dispatch a function, you need to use a useAppDispatch hook

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>() 

export default store
```